# Complete stripping of URL with jquery

Tags: jquery, parsing, url, split, strip

This might be pretty straight forward. But i can't figure out a stable solution.

For example:
http://site1.com/promotion

I want to strip my url so i only get the "site1"-part of the URL.

I tried with:

```
var url = window.location.href.split('http://')[1];
var stripOne = url.split('/')[0];
var stripTwo = stripOne.split('.')[0];
```

But that comes out inconsistent depending on whether or not the url contains www. or not.

**UPDATED WITH CORRECT ANSWER**

```
var url = window.location.href;
url = url.replace(/http:\/\/(www.)?/,'');
var stripOne = url.split('.')[0];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a replace that will strip out 'http://' and 'www.' (if it exists). You could still fall foul of https URLs with this though -

```
url = url.replace(/http:\/\/(www.)?/,'');
var stripTwo = url.split('.')[0];
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Ux9jx/

Comment: Works like a charm!  
Thank you mr. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
location.host.replace('www.','').split('.')[0]
```

would work?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Regular Expressions . Check [this](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri) out.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.host.split("\.")[0]
```